# JavaScript: Form not validated with OnSubmit

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am new bee to JavaScript. I have a form which is not validated with alert button. I am having a form which is to be submitted without errors. If I submit the forms with the empty fields, an alert message should be popped up.
The following is my code:

```js
function validate_Form() {
  alert('hi how');
  exit;
  var tokenNo = document.forms["myForm"]["txt1"].tokenNo;
  if (tokenNo == null || tokenNo == "") {
    alert("Enter The Token No");
    return false;
  } else {
    document.write("pola");
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <form name="Sec_guard_form" onsubmit="validate_Form()">
    <tr>
      <td>Token No</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="token_no" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Other Property</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="other_prop" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bike Number</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="bike_no" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bike name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="bike_nm" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bike model</td>
      <td>
        <select option="bike model">
          <option value="Activa 3G">Activa 3G</option>
          <option value="shine">shine</option>
          <option value="unicon">unicon</option>
          <option value="yuga">yuga</option>
          <option value="neo">neo</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="cancel" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

The above is my code, for i am using the mozilla firefox as my browser. Is that an issue. My function inside the script is not even called. what am i wrong here...

Comment: use `return validate_Form()` in `<form` tag, and move your script to end of the page

Comment: remove exit from your code...there no exit command in javascript

Comment: ok i will remove exit from it, but how to exit from a particular line in javascript for testing purposes?

Comment: use return statement

Answer (score 1):

You can change your javascript like this :

```
function validate_Form() {
   var form = document.querySelector("form");
   var tokenNo = form.elements.token_no.value;
   if (tokenNo == null || tokenNo == "") {
     alert("Enter The Token No");
     return false;
   } else {
     document.write("pola");
   }

   return false;
}
```

and your html like this:

```
<form name="Sec_guard_form" onsubmit="return validate_Form()">
```

1. exit; doesn't mean anything in javascript. You have to use return. So if you return before the function does anything then it is not useful at all!
2. The syntax you used for selecting form element and getting its value was wrong according to me so I corrected the syntax...
3. Also, you might be wondering why to use return validate_form() in HTML and return false in the function. It is used just for stopping the page to refresh/redirect before the entire function gets executed!

Try this code, it worked for me... I don't know what hi how was for so I eliminated it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling function on your submit button Please use this to call function first.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate_Form()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<form name="Sec_guard_form" onsubmit="validate_Form()">
```

to

```
<form name="Sec_guard_form" onsubmit="return validate_Form()">
```

Comment: I gave return validate_form(), but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Complete html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
 <form id="Sec_guard_form" onsubmit="return validate_Form();" method="post">
    <tr>
      <td>Token No</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="token_no" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Other Property</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="other_prop" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bike Number</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="bike_no" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bike name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="bike_nm" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bike model</td>
      <td>
        <select option="bike model">
          <option value="Activa 3G">Activa 3G</option>
          <option value="shine">shine</option>
          <option value="unicon">unicon</option>
          <option value="yuga">yuga</option>
          <option value="neo">neo</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="cancel" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
<script>

  function validate_Form() 
    {   alert('hi how');
            var tokenNo = document.getElementById("Sec_guard_form")["token_no"].value;

            if (tokenNo == null || tokenNo  == "")
        {
            alert("Enter The Token No");
            return false;
        }
            else
        {
            document.write("pola");
        }

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working fine

Comment: I have edited code and added complete code and its working fine in firefox